# Component oriented design: Problems with dependencies in dialogs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, oop, unity-container

I have a modular application, it behaves quite like a plugin system. Module B is dependent on Module A. When B is present, then some dialogs (titles etc.) need to be altered in Module A. Also, a different entity should be used for a list when Module B is present, which I want to include in Module B, so A doesn't know about it during compile time. Creating an abstract base in A for the entity is something I want to avoid as well.

How would you implement this requirement? The modules can communicate in various ways:

```
1.) Microsoft Unity is used for Object creation and dependency injection
2.) The modules can communicate via a Message-System.
3.) There's an EventAggregator which all the modules can use
```

I don't want to sublcass the dialog in Module B and just alter the typemapping in unity, because then I'd have to provide the whole dialog in another module. Also, if some other module wants to make other changes to the dialog, it'd be impossible.

Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing specific details, I would use **interfaces** to blend the plug-in components/modules. Require that each plug-in component implement an interface -- say **IPluginComponent** or whatever makes sense.  (Actually, only components that must communicate or interact would actually be *required* to implement the interface.) Once all modules are loaded, the host application can fire methods or events on the components.

Personally, I like to keep things **data-driven** and simple as much as possible; so I might favor a "two-phase" pass through the modules. This keeps the dependencies between modules simple. So in the first phase, when all components are loaded, the host application fires the "*ContributeSharedData(Context ctx)*" method, where each component sets any values in a shared context. (This might also be called "*Init(ctx)*".) The context might be as simple as a name-value-pair collection, e.g. Module B says *coll["ModuleB_Installed"] = true*, or it could add itself to a list of modules, or... the possibilities are endless.  The context can be whatever class or structure is required to enable these components to work together.

The next pass -- if required -- would be for the components/modules to **configure** themselves based on the shared context. So the host might run through all the modules supporting the shared interface and fire the "Configure" method or event.  Then ModuleA for instance can look in the context and see that ModuleB is installed, and configure its interface accordingly.

If an interface doesn't make sense for your situation, you can use any method of contributing shared data in a generic way to a common location, e.g. messaging or other common classes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like the SharedContex idea very much! It seems extensible.